# Can't make curl POST within a recursive shell function..?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, recursion

I'm trying to do a `curl` POST to a URL, that may cause a sequence of redirects (301) to actual URL that is BASIC authentication protected. As it turned out that `-L` option will not help much in this case, I thought I'd give it a try with writing a case-specific shell script with a recursive function, just to prove the concept. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

WORK_DIR=/some/dir
MY_URL=http://redirect.me/some/service
MY_FILE=output.bin

follow_redirect() {

echo "Input URL is $1"

local status_code="$(curl -s -X POST --data-binary @${WORK_DIR}/postdata.txt -u myuser:mypass \
-o ${WORK_DIR}/${MY_FILE} -D ${WORK_DIR}/headers.out -w "%{http_code}" "$1" --header "X-Custom-Header:Whatever")"

echo "Status code is $status_code"

if [ $status_code -eq "301" ]; then
  # extract Location header value
  local loc_line="$(cat ${WORK_DIR}/headers.out | grep Location)"
  local sub_url=${loc_line:10}
  echo "HTTP redirect to: $sub_url"
  follow_redirect "$sub_url"
elif [ $status_code -eq "200" ]; then
  echo "HTTP OK"
  return
else
  echo "HTTP request failed"
  return
fi

}

# do the call
follow_redirect "$MY_URL"
```

Short description: the idea was to try to do the call, and obtain the status code. If code is 301, do recursive call, passing in new URL, previously extracted from the `Location` header (headers are dumped to a temporary file, as can be seen).

What I get as the output is this:

```
Input URL is http://redirect.me/some/service
Status code is 301
HTTP redirect to: http://actual.url/some/service
Input URL is http://actual.url/some/service
Status code is 000
HTTP request failed
```

For some reason, first recursive `curl` call fails with status code of `000`, as if I passed in an empty input URL, or something (but input URL is actually printed out correctly). I also tried substituting all parameterized file system paths with hard-coded values, to make sure it's not something there, but the result is the same. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here...?

Comment: @4ae1e1 did you catch my comment above that  `-L` does not work in this case (authentication required)..? `curl` does not seem to propagate auth.data

Comment: Hmm... I did not try that. I'll try it out.

Comment: Upon further inspection, you should probably use `--location-trusted` instead of `-L`, `--location`. Ref: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--location-trusted.

Comment: Actually, what seems to have solved this by only using `curl` is not only specifying `--location-trusted` but `--post301` as well, in order to preserve original POST request so it does not get converted to GET upon redirect. Feel free to compose an answer out of your comments, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yeah that's also in the man page, under `-L,--location`; I wasn't aware since I never had a relevant use case. I'm usually reluctant to write trivia direct quotation answers, so feel free to write it up yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what seems to have solved this by only using `curl` is not only specifying `--location-trusted` but `--post301` as well, in order to preserve original POST request so it does not get converted to GET upon redirect.
                    – Less